Managing problems of class imbalance in machine learning models using spatial data in R
I am trying to simultaneously perform feature selection and hyperparameter tuning on stacked learners (glmnet and rpart). However, I am encountering the following error message with the classif.glmnet learner of the mlr3 package.
Error in lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed
This happened PipeOp classif.glmnet's $train()

I think this error is due to an imbalance between the classes (0 and 1) of the target feature during the stacking process. I am working with spatial data, and the classes are balanced before the stacking process.
I have tried several potential solutions but none have worked:

Setting stratify = TRUE
Testing multiple variables to represent spatial units in the leave-location-and-time-out resampling method (columns "L1_ID", "L2_ID", "L3_ID" in the dataset)
Removing temporal units (column "year" in the dataset)
Using a different spatial resampling method (spcv_env)

Are there other solutions to balance the classes? For example, is there a way to exclude spatial and/or temporal units with few observations? Your help would be greatly appreciated.
Update: could PipeOpClassBalancing and PipeOpSmote be solutions to explore, even if initially I do not have an imbalanced target feature?
Here are the counts of observations in the units:
> table(data$L1_ID)

   3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   12   13   14   15 
  82    9  751  467   21 1286  986  314   86  248  138  108 
> table(data$L2_ID)

 3.2  3.3  4.1  5.1  5.2  5.3  5.4  6.1  6.2  7.1  8.1  8.2  8.3  8.4  8.5  9.2  9.3  9.4  9.5  9.6 10.1 10.2 12.1 12.2 13.1 13.2 13.3 13.4 13.5 13.6 14.1 14.2 14.3 14.4 14.5 15.1 15.2 15.3 15.4 
   3   79    9  199  226  118  208   21  446   21  343  101  432  217  193  262  262  357   50   55  144  170   67   19   40   74   36   41   46   11   27    5   47   33   26   44   25    3   22 
15.5 15.6 
   9    5 
> table(data$L3_ID)

10.1.1 10.1.2 10.1.3 10.1.4 10.1.5 10.1.7 10.1.8 10.2.2 10.2.4 12.1.1 12.1.2 12.2.1 13.1.1 13.2.1 13.3.1 13.4.1 13.4.2 13.5.1 13.5.2 13.6.1 13.6.2 14.1.1 14.1.2 14.2.1 14.3.1 14.3.2 14.4.1 14.4.2 
    28     40     12     42      6      7      9     54    116     29     38     19     40     74     36      4     37     11     35      8      3     15     12      5      7     40     21      5 
14.4.3 14.5.1 14.5.2 15.1.1 15.1.2 15.2.1 15.2.2 15.2.3 15.3.1 15.4.1 15.5.1 15.5.2 15.6.1  3.2.2  3.3.2  4.1.2  5.1.2  5.1.3  5.1.5  5.1.6  5.2.1  5.2.2  5.2.3  5.3.1  5.3.3  5.4.1  5.4.2  5.4.3 
     7      3     23     14     30      3      9     13      3     22      4      5      5      3     79      9     77     35     21     66    106     18    102    111      7    144     43     21 
 6.1.5  6.2.1 6.2.10 6.2.11 6.2.12 6.2.13 6.2.14 6.2.15  6.2.2  6.2.3  6.2.4  6.2.5  6.2.6  6.2.7  6.2.8  6.2.9  7.1.6  7.1.7  7.1.8  7.1.9  8.1.1 8.1.10  8.1.2  8.1.3  8.1.4  8.1.5  8.1.6  8.1.7 
    21     31     83      6      1      3     21     15     35    102     72     14      4     15      9     35      3      1     13      4     86     22     21     19     47     15     19     44 
 8.1.8  8.1.9  8.2.1  8.2.2  8.2.3  8.2.4  8.3.1  8.3.2  8.3.3  8.3.4  8.3.5  8.3.6  8.3.7  8.3.8  8.4.1  8.4.2  8.4.3  8.4.4  8.4.5  8.4.6  8.4.7  8.4.8  8.4.9  8.5.1  8.5.2  8.5.3  8.5.4  9.2.1 
    54     16     19     20     31     31     23     53     33     92    107     23     78     23     53     33     12     31     43      5      7     14     19     44     40     99     10    118 
 9.2.2  9.2.3  9.2.4  9.3.1  9.3.3  9.3.4  9.4.1  9.4.2  9.4.3  9.4.4  9.4.5  9.4.6  9.4.7  9.5.1  9.6.1 
    27     74     43    120    128     14     87     89     68      8     42     43     20     50     55 
> table(data$year)

2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 
 134  132  140  166  164  160  196  206  252  300  434  458  556  604  594

Here are my data:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hkjs79i89gjz0j5mjlbj8/Data.csv?rlkey=08yuzet3mjr9gcezkryo93vqm&st=hfv2cbeo&dl=0
Here is my code:
set.seed(1)
source("H:/Marine/PipeOpLearnerCV_mod.R")
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Marine/Downloads/Data.csv")
data$presence <- as.factor(data$presence)
## data$L3_ID <- as.factor(data$L3_ID)
data$L2_ID <- as.factor(data$L2_ID)
## data$L1_ID <- as.factor(data$L1_ID)
data$year <- as.factor(data$year)
## summary(data)

data <- data[, !((names(data) %in% c("L1_ID", "L3_ID")))]
task <- mlr3spatial::as_task_classif_st(x = data, target = "presence", positive = "1", coordinate_names = c("x", "y"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
task$set_col_roles("L2_ID", roles = "space")
task$set_col_roles("year", roles = "time")
summary(task)

learner_glmnet <- mlr3tuningspaces::lts(mlr3::lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob"))
learner_rpart <- mlr3tuningspaces::lts(mlr3::lrn("classif.rpart", predict_type = "prob"))
learner_glmnet_cv <- PipeOpLearnerCV_mod$new(learner = learner_glmnet, id = "learner_glmnet_cv", param_vals = list(resampling.method = "sptcv_cstf", resampling.folds = 2))
learner_rpart_cv <- PipeOpLearnerCV_mod$new(learner = learner_rpart, id = "learner_rpart_cv", param_vals = list(resampling.method = "sptcv_cstf", resampling.folds = 2))

learner_avg <- mlr3pipelines::LearnerClassifAvg$new(id = "classif.avg")
learner_avg$predict_type  <- "prob"
learner_avg$param_set$values$measure <- "classif.auc"

level_0_graph <- mlr3pipelines::gunion(list(learner_glmnet_cv, learner_rpart_cv)) %>>% mlr3pipelines::po("featureunion")
level_0_and_1_graph <- level_0_graph %>>% learner_avg
level_0_and_1_graph_learner <- mlr3::as_learner(level_0_and_1_graph)

tuning <- mlr3tuning::auto_tuner(tuner = mlr3tuning::tnr("mbo"), 
                                 learner = level_0_and_1_graph_learner,
                                 resampling = mlr3::rsmp("sptcv_cstf", folds = 2, stratify = TRUE),
                                 measure = mlr3::msr("classif.auc"),
                                 terminator = mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 2, k = 0))

feature_selection <- mlr3fselect::auto_fselector(fselector = mlr3fselect::fs("sequential", strategy = "sfs", min_features = 2),
                                                 learner = tuning,
                                                 resampling = mlr3::rsmp("sptcv_cstf", folds = 2, stratify = TRUE),
                                                 measure = mlr3::msr("classif.auc"),
                                                 terminator = mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 2, k = 0))

stacking <- mlr3::resample(task = task, 
                           learner = feature_selection, 
                           resampling = mlr3::rsmp("sptcv_cstf", folds = 2, stratify = TRUE), 
                           store_models = TRUE)

Here is the function PipeOpLearnerCV_mod.R to run my code:
PipeOpLearnerCV_mod = R6Class("PipeOpLearnerCV_mod",
                              inherit = PipeOpTaskPreproc,
                              public = list(
                                initialize = function(learner, id = NULL, param_vals = list()) {
                                  private$.learner = as_learner(learner, clone = TRUE)
                                  if (mlr3pipelines:::paradox_info$is_old) {
                                    private$.learner$param_set$set_id = ""
                                  }
                                  ########################################################################
                                  ## My edits
                                  id = private$.learner$id
                                  ## id = id %??% private$.learner$id
                                  # FIXME: can be changed when mlr-org/mlr3#470 has an answer
                                  ########################################
                                  type = private$.learner$task_type
                                  task_type = mlr_reflections$task_types[type, mult = "first"]$task
                                  
                                  ########################################################################
                                  ## My edits
                                  private$.crossval_param_set = ps(
                                    method = p_fct(levels = c("cv", "insample", "sptcv_cstf", "repeated_sptcv_cstf"), tags = c("train", "required")),
                                    folds = p_int(lower = 2L, upper = Inf, tags = c("train", "required")), 
                                    repeats = p_int(lower = 1L, upper = Inf),
                                    keep_response = p_lgl(tags = c("train", "required"))
                                  )
                                  ########################################
                                  private$.crossval_param_set$values = list(method = "cv", folds = 3, keep_response = FALSE)
                                  if (mlr3pipelines:::paradox_info$is_old) {
                                    private$.crossval_param_set$set_id = "resampling"
                                  }
                                  # Dependencies in paradox have been broken from the start and this is known since at least a year:
                                  # https://github.com/mlr-org/paradox/issues/216
                                  # The following would make it _impossible_ to set "method" to "insample", because then "folds"
                                  # is both _required_ (required tag above) and at the same time must be unset (because of this
                                  # dependency). We will opt for the least annoying behaviour here and just not use dependencies
                                  # in PipeOp ParamSets.
                                  # private$.crossval_param_set$add_dep("folds", "method", CondEqual$new("cv"))  # don't do this.
                                  
                                  super$initialize(id, alist(resampling = private$.crossval_param_set, private$.learner$param_set), param_vals = param_vals, can_subset_cols = TRUE, task_type = task_type, tags = c("learner", "ensemble"))
                                }
                                
                              ),
                              active = list(
                                learner = function(val) {
                                  if (!missing(val)) {
                                    if (!identical(val, private$.learner)) {
                                      stop("$learner is read-only.")
                                    }
                                  }
                                  private$.learner
                                },
                                learner_model = function(val) {
                                  if (!missing(val)) {
                                    if (!identical(val, private$.learner)) {
                                      stop("$learner_model is read-only.")
                                    }
                                  }
                                  if (is.null(self$state) || is_noop(self$state)) {
                                    private$.learner
                                  } else {
                                    multiplicity_recurse(self$state, clone_with_state, learner = private$.learner)
                                  }
                                },
                                predict_type = function(val) {
                                  if (!missing(val)) {
                                    assert_subset(val, names(mlr_reflections$learner_predict_types[[private$.learner$task_type]]))
                                    private$.learner$predict_type = val
                                  }
                                  private$.learner$predict_type
                                }
                              ),
                              private = list(
                                .train_task = function(task) {
                                  on.exit({private$.learner$state = NULL})
                                  
                                  # Train a learner for predicting
                                  self$state = private$.learner$train(task)$state
                                  pv = private$.crossval_param_set$values
                                  
                                  # Compute CV Predictions
                                  if (pv$method != "insample") {
                                    rdesc = mlr_resamplings$get(pv$method)
                                    if (pv$method == "cv") rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds)
                                    ########################################################################
                                    ## My edits
                                    if (pv$method == "sptcv_cstf") rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds, stratify = TRUE)
                                    if (pv$method == "repeated_sptcv_cstf") rdesc$param_set$values = list(folds = pv$folds, repeats = pv$repeats, stratify = TRUE)
                                    ########################################################################
                                    rr = resample(task, private$.learner, rdesc)
                                    prds = as.data.table(rr$prediction(predict_sets = "test"))
                                  } else {
                                    prds = as.data.table(private$.learner$predict(task))
                                  }
                                  
                                  private$pred_to_task(prds, task)
                                },
                                
                                .predict_task = function(task) {
                                  on.exit({private$.learner$state = NULL})
                                  private$.learner$state = self$state
                                  prediction = as.data.table(private$.learner$predict(task))
                                  private$pred_to_task(prediction, task)
                                },
                                
                                pred_to_task = function(prds, task) {
                                  if (!is.null(prds$truth)) prds[, truth := NULL]
                                  if (!self$param_set$values$resampling.keep_response && self$learner$predict_type == "prob") {
                                    prds[, response := NULL]
                                  }
                                  renaming = setdiff(colnames(prds), c("row_id", "row_ids"))
                                  data.table::setnames(prds, renaming, sprintf("%s.%s", self$id, renaming))
                                  
                                  # This can be simplified for mlr3 >= 0.11.0;
                                  # will be always "row_ids"
                                  row_id_col = intersect(colnames(prds), c("row_id", "row_ids"))
                                  data.table::setnames(prds, old = row_id_col, new = task$backend$primary_key)
                                  task$select(character(0))$cbind(prds)
                                },
                                .crossval_param_set = NULL,
                                .learner = NULL,
                                .additional_phash_input = function() private$.learner$phash
                              )
)

mlr_pipeops$add("learner_cv", PipeOpLearnerCV_mod, list(R6Class("Learner", public = list(id = "learner_cv", task_type = "classif", param_set = ps()))$new()))

